# If a Column is incremented and then used in the same UPDATE query to set another Column's value, which value will it hold?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Given the query...

```
UPDATE
   Table1
SET
   col1 = col1 + 1,
   col2 = col1 * 2
WHERE
   colID = 1
```

...if `col1` equals `1` **before** the query is executed, will `col2` be set to `2` or `4` **after** the query is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give it a try.  But here you go:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b6de/1

Col2 updates to 4.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!